# Exchange mail users cannot send to certain lists

Tags: email, exchange-2010, distribution-lists

First of all, everyone's on Exchange 2010 using OWA

I have a dynamic distribution list that contains all users in my domain called 'staff'.  I can send to this list, other people can send to this list, but I have one user that cannot send to this list. Sending to this list gives the user an email back with the error:

> Delivery has failed to these
>   recipients or groups: Staff
>
> The e-mail address you entered
>   couldn't be found. Please check the
>   recipient's e-mail address and try to
>   resend the message. If the problem
>   continues, please contact your
>   helpdesk.

and then a bunch of diagnostic information that I don't want to paste here because I don't want to have to censor all of the sensitive information contained (lazy)

Can you guys throw me some possible reasons why this would happen?  If there are an innumerable number of reasons, where should I start to troubleshoot this?

---

EDIT

One Exchange server inside the network that acts as a transport server, client access server and mailbox server and one Edge Transport server in the DMZ.

Comment: Can you please provide more details? What's your setup like? How many Exchange servers? How many OWA servers?

Comment: Try deleting the entry for the DG from the user's nickname cache in Outlook.

Comment: @joeqwerty, OP says everyone's using OWA.

Comment: @Holo: My bad. I meant to say clear it in OWA. The nickname cache is a feature of OWA with Exchange 2010: http://www.microsoft.com/exchange/2010/en/my/outlook-web-access.aspx

Comment: @blusb6: The diagnostic information would actually help. Might you run a Find and Replace to sanitize it and post it here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that it was what everyone was suggesting.  When I made the Staff distribution list from a standard list to a dynamic list, something got messed up.  I went into OWA, brought up the nickname cache (little pop-up menu when typing in the address in a new mail) and hit delete on the name, it removed it from the nickname cache.  When they tried to send again, it sent to the correct list.

Thanks for everyone's help!