# Clear/Remove Exchange 2010 Outlook Web Access (OWA) Cached/AutoComplete Addresses

Tags: exchange-2010, cache, outlook-web-app

Does anyone know how to clear the autocomplete/cached addresses from a users mailbox in Exchange 2010 OWA?  I've cleared the address from the N2K cache on their local machine, but it still shows via OWA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's similar to this problem here:  [Exchange mail users cannot send to certain lists](https://serverfault.com/questions/235437/exchange-mail-users-cannot-send-to-certain-lists)

Bring up a new email in OWA, start to type the offending address, when it come's up, hit delete.  That should clear it.

Comment: Perfect...I'm on a mac so I needed to do fn + delete to issue the same key command as delete on a windows keyboard. Hopefully this extra bit of info will help out someone.

Answer (score 0):

I found areally helpful guide at the link below:

[How to clear the Autocomplete list in Outlook 2010](http://cyberst0rm.blogspot.com/2011/07/how-to-clear-autocomplete-list-in.html)

Comment: Please do not post links to blogs, as noone can be sure those still exists when someone finds this question in the future. You should instead post some of the useful content here, and then link to the blog for reference.